# Multiple apk approach for a game

Tags: android, resources, apk, publishing

I'm planning to use the Multiple apk approach to my current project, since it has a big number of drawables for every density and the apk file is big right now. Are there any pitfalls in using this kind of approach? By the way, does the download statistics "sum up" on the Android Market for Multiple apk's? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean you want to design for different device resolution?but im confirm that  Android Market doesnot sum up

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad, Yes, you're right. I want every apk to have only one set of resources for a concrete resolution. And you mean, for example, that I have 1000 downloads from mdpi device users and 10000 downloads from hdpi device users - an mdpi user coming to Market will see a number of 1000 downloads, not 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As our comment discussion

In my experience apk size does not affect performance of application.As if you are using hdpi
device then ldpi resource will not load.So device will load only the resource required by 
current device.And i think this is best approach.

Second If you want to make three application instead of one for ldpi,hdpi,and mdpi then its very time consuming.and it cannot sum the download of all three application.Android gave three option of ldpi,hdpi,mdpi.So we have to use it.

Hope you got my point

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! That was exactly what I was asking for!